# Use variable from one program written in C++ on a C# Project

Tags: c#, c++, variables, share

I have my own program written in C# and I need to make use of 4 variables in another program written in C++

The program in C++ has a timer which reads a com port and translates the bits into x, y and z double variables.

So far what I've done is write a text file in every tick of the timer and then read that text file with my C# program.

I was wondering.. Is there a way for my C# program to access the memory of the C++ program and read the variables from there?

Comment: Use P/Invoke, or port the C++ code to C# (or C++/CLI)

Comment: Interesting, I will be checking what you suggest, thanks Slaks

Comment: Lots of ways -- besides all the OS-provided inter-process communication stuff (sockets & shared memory come to mind), you can extract the relevant part of your C++ program into a DLL and use that (either via a C++/CLI wrapper or by exposing a C interface and using P/Invoke).

Comment: An easier solution than reading raw memory from a program is [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) as @Cameron suggested, but this is dependent on the target supporting an IPC method. Since you seem to have access to the code for the target program, this shouldn't be an issue.